# Keeping track of info

Tags: blogs

My memory is not the best, so I like to keep a blog using WordPress which I keep track of all the programming and IT related things I learn.  This way, when I need it again I can just search and go back and look at it.

Using WordPress has been good, but its editing really sucks and I would like something with more of a plain text system.

I know many other people do this. If you do, can you recommend the system you use?  Here's mine so far http://knife-bst.com/tech/

As you can see with git commands -- it becomes a big -. So WordPress really is not working too well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiki)? It will take care of maintaining all of its own history, and editing is not that difficult.

Comment: thanks for the edits and do you recommend any particular wiki.

Comment: I like DokuWiki (http://www.dokuwiki.org/features). There are others, of course, but that's the one I have the most experience with.

Answer (score 2):

This is just the kind of thing [Evernote](http://www.evernote.com/) is for.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [google docs and spreadsheets](http://docs.google.com). It's excellent for this sort of thing!